# Django - CSS file not linking with template correctly

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

In my project, I attempt to link my html template to a CSS file that I have in my static folder. I have added **STATIC_ROOT**, **STATIC_URL** and **STATICFILES_DIRS** to my settings.py.

In my *static* folder, I have a folder called *styles*, and within that, I have a file named **signup.css** . I have also ran *python manage.py collectstatic*.

In my template I attempt to reference that CSS file to change the colour of my *h1*, however no change occurs.

**Template**:

```
{% load static %}
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/signup.css' %}">
    </head>
    <h1>YO</h1>
    <div id="signupformdiv">
        <form class="signupform" action="{% url 'signup' %}">

        </form>
    </div>
```

**signup.css:**

```
h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

The colour of my h1 remains black. Does anybody know the issue? Thank you.

**Source Code**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Instagram</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="/static/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/static/favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
    <h5 class="my-0 mr-md-auto font-weight-normal"><a class="text-dark">Instagram</a></h5>
    <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/signup.css">
    </head>
    <h1>YO</h1>
    <div id="signupformdiv">
        <form class="signupform" action="/users/signup/">

        </form>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

ERROR in browser:
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

**settings.py**:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'instagram/static/')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**Project Structure:**
instagram-project is root,
subfolder called instagram, and within I have a folder named 'static'

Inside root directory, I have a static folder, where all static files are sent to.

Inside users app, I have a folder called templates, where my template is stored.

** BASE.HTML **

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Instagram</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/signup.css' %}">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}" />

</head>
```

Comment: provide your settings.py and the tree of the directory of the whole django project

Comment: Could you please show the source code of what rendered in your browser using `View Page Source`?

Comment: @aminrd Please check my original post.

Comment: @aminrd I have added in the source code.

Comment: Are you using this template inside another template? Because there are two `<head></head>` tags in this file

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed Please check the error I am receiving in the browser from my original post.

Comment: @aminrd Yes, I am extending a template.

Comment: @aminrd Please check my original post. I have provided the error I received.

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed I have provided settings.py in my original post, however I am unsure on how to provided a tree of my whole Django project. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What's the structure of your project root??

Comment: @PwnSauceDesigns Please check my updated post.

Comment: @PwnSauceDesigns This was the best structure I could describe. I am a newbie to development so I am sorry if it is inefficient. If so please tell me how I can tell you my project structure.

Comment: @eweee - Check out Template Inheritance: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance  
It will help you place your css in the main `<head>` instead of creating a second one.

Comment: @eweee your project root is like `projectcontainer/`, and inside that is the `manage.py` file, as well as every sub folder.

Comment: @Ben Hey, I have added my css link inside my .base.html head as Django docs stated, however bow I am getting the error:  .Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Ben . Please check my original post as I have shown some code from the inherited template

Comment: have a look at the answer and tell me the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the server can't find the your static files not because they don't exist, but because there's no urlpattern for them, [more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/)

```
# project urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = []
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This should solve it

Comment: One question. When I want to edit the CSS file, would I edit it in the static folder within the root of my project, or the edit in the static folder within my instagram folder, then run collectstatic?

Comment: Actually I have solved. You have to edit the file in your static folder which you added into STATICFILES_DIRS, and then you have to perform a collectstatic.

Comment: Well, I didn't see the comment on time, Glad it worked

Comment: Btw this won't happen after deployment because you'll be using a server for static files *other than your code* like images & these things, perheps you'd use something like amazon S3